# Get Rspec example tags

Tags: rspec

:I'm developing framework to interract Rspec and Testrail. I decided to unite tests to groups by using tags. After finishing test I parse `example` variable, which is `Rspec::Example` object and here I need to get its tags to ignore this test, if it contains specific tag, then set 'blocked' status to it in Testrail. So is there any method, like `example.get_tags` for my case?

It should looks like:

```
it 'test', tag1: true, tag2: true do
  true.should == true
end

after :each do
  example.get_tags #  tag1: true, tag2: true
end
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Found it in `example.metadata`, question closed.